# Transmitting Java agents instrumentation to spawned JVM

Tags: java, javaagents

## Context

I have built a custom Junit runner for my specific needs (testing Java programs that use MPI, but that's not relevant here). The key part of my runner consists in spanwing multiple JVMs to run the tests. I do this using a `ProcessBuilder`.

My custom runner works great, which brings me to my issue:

## The problem

I am using Jacoco with Maven to create test coverage reports. On the tests that use the normal Junit framework, this works fine. However, this is not the case when my custom Junit runner is used.

More specifically, the process running my custom runner is being tracked by Jacoco (I can see it in the "sessions" page of the reports), but the JVMs spawned with the process builder are not.

**Some encouraging signs:** If I manually add the argument `-javaagent:C:\\Users\\Patrick\\.m2\[...]\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.5-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\[...]jacoco.exec` to my process builder, it will work. The spawned JVMs are being tracked by Jacoco and I can see that the classes I am interested in are tracked. But this is not satisfactory, I can't keep this hard-coded argument.

## My question

*Is there a way to obtain the `-javaagent` part of the command from within the running JVM?*

In my case, I would look for potential java agents monitoring my custom Junit runner. If there are any, I would carry them forward to the processes I spawn with the `ProcessBuilder`.

I looked for any signs of agents in the *Properties* (`System.getProperties()`) but I can't find anything there.

I will be happy to provide any additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get most of the VM arguments using [`RuntimeMXBean.getInputArguments()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.management/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html#getInputArguments()):

```
List<String> vmArgs = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments();
```

This list contains (at least on my machine) the entire `-javaagent:...` arguments, among other parameters.